# how can i share a plain text and another file like excel file through one single intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I tried this but it only sends excel file not text
I tried to send text and file in two intents and it works but in one intent no

```
val file = File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ,
        "newfolder/$name.xlsx"
 val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context , "com.example.android.fogara2" , file)
    val sendIntent : Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type="text/plain"
        `package` = "com.whatsapp"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"sometext")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , uri)
        type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
context.startActivity(sendIntent)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577438/how-can-i-share-multiple-files-via-an-intent

Comment: @blackapps that's not my question I  want to send one file with a plain text, not multiple types my code is like what it uses for single type but doesn't work for WhatsApp

Comment: Try  type="image/*"

Comment: `I want to send one file` AND `how can i share a plain text and another file ` do not match.

Comment: @blackapps should I save text somewhere then take its uri to send in multiple send action is a way to send it directly

Comment: It is unclear what you want. And you are not reacting to the point on my remarks.. Difficult conversation..

Comment: @blackapps I want to send a text like "hi how r u " and a .xlsx excel file through Whatsapp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216964/discussion-between---and-blackapps).

Comment: Please try first in general: not to whatsapp but implicit.

Comment: @blackapps ok but how all I found in websites send text as a caption attached with the file but I want to send it in another message